# How do I set my button's height so it's the same as the width?

Tags: android, xml, button, size

I have a couple of buttons, that are supposed to be squares. But I'm not able to set the height to be the same as the width. How do I do that?

I tried to solve the problem with layout_constraintDimensionRatio, but it didn't work, the height was just 0.

This is the code:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/grid_11"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Small"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
```

And this is what I tried:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/grid_11"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Small"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason the height was "0" is because you have not properly set the constraints for your button. Set proper constraints something as below and it will work.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/grid_11"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Small"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"/>
```

Comment: Note:  this would only work if the parent view is a ContraintLayout

Answer (score 0):

Change-

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

To-

```
android:layout_width="@dimen/square_button_size"
android:layout_height="@dimen/square_button_size"
```

and add

```
<dimen name="square_button_size">50dp</dimen>
```

in *res/values/dimen.xml*

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using values from the dimens file. If it is not present in the `res/values` folder, then create a XML file called `dimens.xml` file there. Then add a dimen value stating your value which you want to use for the height and width of the button:

```
<dimen name="btn_size">100dp</dimen>
```

Then you can specify it to the button like this:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/grid_11"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Small"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_size"
            android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
```

This will add the same height width to the button.

Comment: But what if I don't want the button to be a specific size? I want it to fit into the layout, so the width must stay match_parent.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to put it in a ConstraintLayout (which is the easiest answer, @SirkarReddy already suggested it)-  subclass Button and override the onMeasure function so that it will always measure itself as a square.  There is no built in way to get the behavior you want in a RelativeLayout or LinearLayout without some hacking in code.